# How can I find road speed limit in open street map

Tags: php, openstreetmap, overpass-api

How can I find road speed limit in open street map? I am using open street map **`OverPass API`** . I have used following query to find bus stop.

```
<query type="node">
  <has-kv k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
  <has-kv k="name" v="Lichtscheid"/>
</query>
<query type="node">
  <around radius="1000"/>
  <has-kv k="highway" v="bus_stop"/>
</query>
<print/>
```

But I need road Speed Limit.

Comment: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/7927/how-can-i-see-the-speed-limit-of-a-street

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://overpass-turbo.eu/?template=key&key=maxspeed ?

Comment: @tyr Yes.My requirement is when I travel on roads and find those roads maxspeed.

Answer (score 1):

[Elements](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) in OpenStreetMap are described by [tags](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). For speed limits the [maxspeed](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3amaxspeed) tag is used as already noted in tyr's comment. So you have to query for *ways* with the *maxspeed* tag.

Example [Overpass](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) XML query:

```
<osm-script output="json">
  <union>
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="maxspeed"/>
      <bbox-query {{bbox}}/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton"/>
</osm-script>
```

[Result](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Om)

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Let me try and let you know.

Comment: There is no http request for this ? Is it possible to put all this in a url as query parameter?

Comment: Sure there is. Look at the export button or read about [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) which is used as backend.